# How to set up custom behaviour when receiving a notification in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-alertdialog, flutter-notification

I have an app built in flutter and I am sending certain notification via firebase messaging to a given device. When that device receives the notification, I would like that there will be an alarm a bit like when you receive a phone call. I would like the alarm to go on until the user do not open the notification.
Is there an easy way to achieve this in flutter? I s it even possible?
Thanks